# An effective solution for a Control-Monitoring System on a network

Tags: .net, wcf, nservicebus, remote-control

I am going to develop a remote control and monitoring system that will be executed on a network.
I know that the best architecture for systems like this is SOA (or not?). The system includes 2 types of clients and a server. because of the systems behavior its essential that both servers and clients be able to connect to each other. Now there is some questions about it :

1- Should I use a live connection between system parts? because of servers need to have access to the clients on any time.

2 - I wanna develop it with .Net frame work now, but maybe I will need to change the clients or server to java or some thing else in the future, so can I use .net based technologies like WCF to developig this system?

3 - I have seen a tool named "NServiceBus" that seems to be good system for projects in this way but I don't have enough experience on it, can any body tell me about it's advantages for my system?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is overly broad, I'll try to help out.

Starting with #2 - if you don't know the development platform (java or .net) that would clearly influence other choices.

Although both WCF and NServiceBus have interoperability capabilities, there are multiple other factors that would influence the choice - or even using both.

And on question #1 - the term "live connection" isn't specific enough. Also the network topology would influence the design - same LAN vs WAN vs Internet.

If no further details are known, my suggestion would be to hire someone who's built this kind of thing before and let them do their thing.

Comment: My development platform is .Net now, but later we may need to have some parts of system on other platforms like java. Imagine we have several clients that should be controlled and several servers that should control the clients. clients need to send reports to the servers and servers need to access the clients at any time !

Comment: Using an interoperable queuing system like RabbitMQ would probably be enough to deal with other platforms like Java.